# CSS en Chrome, Edge.. se ven bien pero no safari

Tags: html, css3

Estoy modificando una web y tanto en la versión desktop como móvil se ve bien, el problema es que en safari se ve todo descuadrado...
Web en Chrome:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora el mismo bloque en safari...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura de la página es:

- Imagen con título
- Slider de imágenes
- Primer bloque "¿Qué podemos hacer por tu empresa?

En chrome, edge... se ve bien, pero en safari no se ve el carrusel (que lo tengo con un display: none en móvil) y como se puede apreciar en la imagen de safari, el bloque de texto se sube principio de la página.
Código CSS:

```
/*css slider*/
.center-y{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.center-x{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#slider-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 45%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 2rem;
    top: -39rem !important;
    margin-bottom: 30rem;
}
.slide{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.slide img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
.slider-arrow{
    color: #041e42;
    font-size: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}
#arrow-prev{
    left:20px;

}
#arrow-next{
    right: 20px;
}
#dots-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.dot-nav{
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 8px;
    border: 2px solid #d6d6d6;
}
.dot-nav:hover{
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
}
.active-dot{
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
}
```

Es como si algunos elementos css no me funcionaran en safari.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hay propiedades de CSS que necesitan de un prefijo para funcionar en un navegador determinado. En este caso la propiedad transform necesitaría de los prefijos fijados para cada navegador.

```
.center-y{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);

    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%); /* Versiones antiguas de Chrome (Motor WebKit) */
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%); /* Versiones antiguas de Firefox (Motor Gecko) */
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);/* Versiones antiguas de IE (Motor Trident) */
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);/* Versiones antiguas de Opera (Motor Presto) */
}
```

Como es muy complicado obtener una lista de funcionalidades implementadas en cada navegador, algo que puede variar incluso en cuestión poco tiempo, te recomiendo seguir alguna página donde vayan actualizando las funcionalidades.
Esta puede ser una de ellas, donde te muestra lo que te comente del prefijo.
https://www.caniuse.com/?search=css%20transform